# How is Bower working without .bowerrc file

Tags: bower, frontend, bower-install

I appreciate this is not a real problem, just curious...

I'm using bower version `1.7.2` and all my projects so far have a `.bowerrc` file in the main project folder.

On my current project (through an oversight with .gitignore) I lost the `.bowerrc` file. ***However*** bower still works just fine and everything gets created where I want it.

I've read the docs on the Bower site and there is nothing to suggest that it will work without the `.bowerrc` file, and plenty on stackoverflow suggests that I need the `.bowerrc` file  - ALSO - there isn't a `.bowerrc` file in the file tree between the project folder and root (although there are plenty around in folders that have different paths)

**My question then is**: does bower work ok without a .bowerrc file (e.g. defaulting to directory:bower_components) ? or is there a way to see which .bowerrc file my bower is using?

Many thanks for any reply, although completely understandable if you read this and move on, like I said, my problem is that it works, and I don't think it should...

Comment: Yes it is, `bowerrc` requires only for special cases (like download path)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the [docs](http://bower.io/docs/config/) specify, the .bowerrc file can be either in the project dir, the user home (i.e ~/.bowerrc - depends on your OS) or the root dir.

If you didn't put it anywhere Bower uses defaults as specified [here](https://github.com/bower/spec/blob/master/config.md).
And to answer your question - the default directory for bower packages is `bower_components`

Answer (score -1):

Yes , I tested in my project with out .bowerrc I am able to install packages with bower.If we don't specify the .bowerrc file bower_components directory is creating in the root directly which is default. If we want "bower_components" to be in specific location that should be specified in the .bowerrc file.

For example if we want  bower_components folder in "app" folder

bowerrc file should specify directory location : **"directory": "app/bower_components",**

But while downloading packages from git ,if you computer has any proxy settings that need to be configured in .bowerrc file. If we don't specify the proxy settings in .bowerrc we wont be able to download packages form git.